# How to change pictures position?

Tags: views, theming, media

I'm doing a website about tips and tricks to save money. Everything is working fine, except the visual identity, which sucks a bit.

I've tried to change the views to give my articles a good looking, but it's still very ugly, as you can see in the homepage for example : http://etu15.hes.planethoster.org/d8/

I'd like to find a wysiwyg editor which allow me to change the position and the size of my picture in my articles (or any modules which can do that). I'm currently using CKeditor, but I can't make a lot of modifications.

Thanks !

P.S. : printscreen of the "manage fields", "manage display" and the view

[image: view]

[image: manage fields]

[image: manage display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a view that displays "Content" instead of "Fields" form the "Show" setting.

[image: how rows should be styled]

Through that, you can set the view to utilize either the default display mode for the node, the teaser mode or another custom display mode..  Using the display mode approach, your view will render each node, respecting your WYSIWYG content and (left/center/right) aligned inline images (assuming you haven't added custom css to automatically center the images at all times).

Alternatively, you can add css to alternate the images (left and right) aligned with the content by using the `.views-row:nth-child() .views-field-field-image` identifier, specifying any custom alternating sequence in the nth-child.  If you simply want to alternate every other row, you can enable the **"Add striping"** option in the **"Unformatted List > Settings"** of the view.

[image: "Add striping" option]

Comment: Thank your for your reply, unfortunately, it's not possible to manage things like snippets with the content mod.

Comment: I've tried and now I've lost my homepage view :'( 

There is no more content in my homepage...do you know why ?

Comment: If you tried the render content option for Unformatted List, what display type/mode did you set for the content to show as in the view?  Is there a configuration set for it when you go to Structure > Content Types > [your node type] > Manage Display?  You may need a template modification for that to appear?

Comment: Also, did you create a new view block for the view?  If so, did you assign the block to the homepage <front> in Structure > Block Layout

Comment: Hi Anson, 

Thank you for your replies ! There is a configuration for my "article". But I'm a bit confused about the view block. There is the block layout for my template, and there also is a "customizable blocks library" I didn't touch. What should I do ?

Comment: The correct path for my frontpage view is "node", right ?

Comment: In views, your custom view should be of the "block" type.  Then in Structure > Block Layout, you want to add your block (generated by views) to the Main Content (or other applicable) region of the theme, assigned to the homepage using <front>

Comment: Finally, I did a new view for the frontpage, which is working. But it's still ugly :D

Comment: If the view is set to "Show" "Content", you'll may still need to apply some basic styling to your display mode for the content type.  It would probably help if you edited this question and posted screenshots of your "manage fields" and "manage display" tabs for the content type in question, as well as of the "edit view" page.

Comment: I just did it !

Comment: check out my response to your other question on the stack:  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253222/loose-frontpage-content/253247#253247,   i think you want to either change the path for the view or make it a block rather than a page

Comment: thank your for your patience Anson. I think I'll give a try to Bootstrap, which seems fit more to my needs.