# Loose frontpage content

Tags: views

I've just tried to change my frontpage view settings (display : fields -> content). After that, my frontpage is empty, despite my settings :

[image: frontpage settings]

The checkbox "promoted to frontpage" is marked for all my articles. I don't understand. Could you help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal Views can be used to setup a dynamic page, a block to insert on another drupal generated page, custom backend administration pages, and much more. One "view" can have multiple display modes/formats.

- Clicking the ADD button (denoted by #1 in the attached screenshot) will list possible types of views you can add to an existing view (it typically keeps settings across display modes consistent, unless you choose "this display only" in top left of popup dialogs while editing various settings).
- The top of the middle section (denoted by #2 in the attached screenshot) will indicate specific settings for that particular view display mode.

[image: view edit form]

Based on the screenshot you've provided, it looks as if you've setup this view (as a page); you need to assign a custom route/path for the page such as /custom-homepage.  Then, in Configuration > System > Site Information, set the path to the front page to be /custom-homepage.

However, if you are simply trying to add a section to the existing homepage, you want to create a block with views, not a page.  Refer to https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/create-a-simple-block-view

It guides you through setting up a block in views and placing it on a page.

Comment: Thank you Anson, 

But I still don't understand why it wasn't working anymore with the initial frontpage view, despite the rightful path.